# Slumdog millionaire (13)

Tags: knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about the 250.000 Euro question:

> During the next commercial break, Prem Kumar moved his face really 
>   close to mine. In a low voice, he made an offending remark that I'm 
>   not going to repeat here.  Strangely enough, when the show resumed, 
>   he beamed at me with a gaze of pure paternal pride, and even chuckled 
>   at my first remark.
>
> The 250.000 Euro question was a catastrophe, and I did not know any 
>   of the three terms mentioned in it, strange and peculiar sounding 
>   terms indeed.  I decided to use the answers to get some better insight. 
>   At this level of the show, every wrong answer actually fits part of 
>   the question, and the trick is to identify the answers that do not 
>   fit more than that.
>
> Answer A almost fit the first strange term in the question, but I 
>   knew that this was a Japanese product, and that it should have been 
>   spelled with a double-S.  Answer B was obvious nonsense and a pure 
>   give-away for Indian citizens, anyway.  At least the second strange 
>   term in the question was neither Braman nor Visnun.  Nothing in 
>   answer C rang a bell.  Answer D again touched my area of expertise, 
>   and I immediately knew that it had to be wrong: the third strange 
>   term in the question had a letter R in the end that did not belong 
>   there, similarly to Delphir and Basicr.
>
> As I had successfully excluded A, B, and D, the only good answer 
>   was C. And so I said to Prem: "This time I will go for C!". Nailed it!!

***What was the 250.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: I like these puzzles so much I hope Jamal *never* becomes a millionaire!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**New answer with much credit going to Alexis for turning my first answer on its head**

The strange terms are

> Nisan, Sivan, and Adar as figured in my first answer below.

The question becomes

> "What are Nisan, Sivan, and Adar?"

The answers are

> A: American cars (question wording implies that the answer refers to cars that are not Japanese; I think any other kind of car works here), B: Hindu gods, C: months in the Hebrew calendar, and D: Programming languages

**Original answer, contains reasoning that I didn't repeat above**

Answers A is:

> Nisan (almost Nissan, a Japanese car)

B is:

> Sivan (take "Shiva", remove the h and add an n to the end to get "Sivan". The same transformation on "Brahma" nets "Braman",and the transformation on "Vishnu" nets Visnun. Brahma, Shiva and Vishnu are the names of Hindu gods.

D is:

> Adar. Delphi and Basic are programming languages, add R to get Delphir and Basicr. Ada is another programming language.

But the answers are all actually

> Months in the Hebrew calendar.

Determining the question:

> Adar, Nisan, and Sivan all contain Jewish festivals from the Bible.  Tishrei is the only other month that has a Biblical festival, it actually has 3 (or 4 depending on how you look at it). So I conclude that...

*TL,DR:*

> The question is "what month of the Hebrew calendar contains the festivals of Rosh Hashanah, Yom Kippur, and Sukkot?" and answers are A: Nisan, B: Sivan, C: Tishrei, D: Adar.

My only uncertainty with this answer is that it is unclear how Jamal would think the answers fit the strange terms.

Comment: I got Nisan, and I'm ashamed to say I didn't make the connection to the rest. Fantastic answer.

Comment: The answers should be different: What are Adar, Nissan, Sivan? A) Japanese cars B) Hindu gods C) calendar months D) programming languages

Comment: @Alexis I think yours is probably the correct answer, but the order would be Nisan, Sivan, and Adar, based on the wording posed in the question